# How to read data from Sling to Jquery?

Tags: jquery, aem, sling

As part of AEM UI development I have written one Sling Servlet and Jquery. I need to trigger Servlet use Jquery and Read data from Servlet to Jquery? any Help?

My Jquery:

```
window.location.href = Granite.HTTP.externalize("/bin/dam/TimelineVersion"); 

var val=""; // Here I need to Read String Data from Servlet
alert(val);
```

My Sling Servlet:

```
@SlingServlet(paths="/bin/dam/TimelineVersion", methods = "GET", metatype=true)
@Properties({
        @Property(name = "service.pid", value = "com.hpe.dam.author.support.servlet.TimelineVersion", propertyPrivate = false),
        @Property(name = "service.vendor", value = "HPE", propertyPrivate = false) })
public class TimelineVersion extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet{

    @Reference
    private SlingRepository repository;

    public void bindRepository(SlingRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository; 
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            String Data="This value i have to get in Jquery";
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refactor your servlet to actually write out the response (I recommend you send JSON to the browser):

```
@SlingServlet(paths="/bin/dam/TimelineVersion", methods = "GET", metatype=true)
@Properties({
        @Property(name = "service.pid", value = "com.hpe.dam.author.support.servlet.TimelineVersion", propertyPrivate = false),
        @Property(name = "service.vendor", value = "HPE", propertyPrivate = false) })
public class TimelineVersionServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

    @Reference
    private SlingRepository repository;

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimelineVersionServlet.class);

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String data = "This value i have to get in Jquery";
            response.getWriter().write(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
             log.error(e); // handle appropriately
        }
    }
}
```

And the following for your Javascript:

```
$.get('/bin/dam/TimelineVersion')
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function() {
        console.log('[ERROR] Could not perform request');
    });
```

Here's a working example of a Sling Servlet called using jQuery: https://github.com/mickleroy/aem-ajax-search

Comment: Thanks :-) Its working, is there any way get value from Jquery to Servlet ?

Comment: @AsnaRaheem if this answer solved your problem, consider accepting it (to mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in)

Comment: $.get('/bin/dam/TimelineVersion') along with this i need pass a value also to Servlet

Comment: you can specify query parameters using `$.get('/bin/dam/TimelineVersion', {param: 'value'})`. I suggest you look at the documentation for $.get: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/